# ERROR: Error installing oj:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just cloned a repository from GitHub for the first time.

I went to check it out on my local machine, so within the local repository on my mac I ran the following command

bin/rails server

I got the following error:

Could not find activesupport-5.0.0.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

So I then ran the bundle install command as suggested, but then it gave me the following error

An error occurred while installing oj (2.12.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install oj -v '2.12.14'` succeeds before bundling.

So as suggested I ran: gem install oj -v '2.12.14'

Then I got a really long message with warning and an error (see below). Any thoughts?

```
ERROR:  Error installing oj:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/oj-2.12.14/ext/oj

/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170218-3717-1p2bvl9.rb extconf.rb

>>>>> Creating Makefile for ruby version 2.4.0 on x86_64-darwin16 <<<<<

creating Makefile



current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/oj-2.12.14/ext/oj

make "DESTDIR=" clean



current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/oj-2.12.14/ext/oj

make "DESTDIR="

compiling cache8.c

compiling circarray.c

compiling compat.c

compiling dump.c

dump.c:503:8: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]

        cnt = RSTRING_LEN(rstr);

            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:976:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'

     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \

     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:972:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'

     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \

     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

dump.c:503:8: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]

        cnt = RSTRING_LEN(rstr);

            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:977:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'

     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)

     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~

dump.c:1776:39: warning: 'rb_struct_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

        for (i = (int)RSTRUCT_LEN(obj), vp = RSTRUCT_PTR(obj); 0 < i; i--, vp++) {

                                             ^

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:1190:33: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRUCT_PTR'

#define RSTRUCT_PTR(st)         rb_struct_ptr(st)

                                ^

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/intern.h:889:25: note: 'rb_struct_ptr' has been explicitly marked deprecated here

DEPRECATED(const VALUE *rb_struct_ptr(VALUE s));

                        ^

dump.c:1776:37: warning: assigning to 'VALUE *' (aka 'unsigned long *') from 'const VALUE *' (aka 'const unsigned long *') discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]

        for (i = (int)RSTRUCT_LEN(obj), vp = RSTRUCT_PTR(obj); 0 < i; i--, vp++) {

                                           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

4 warnings generated.

compiling err.c

compiling fast.c

fast.c:816:17: warning: 'rb_data_object_alloc' is deprecated: by rb_data_object_wrap [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

    doc->self = rb_data_object_alloc(clas, doc, 0, free_doc_cb);

                ^

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:1379:1: note: 'rb_data_object_alloc' has been explicitly marked deprecated here

rb_data_object_alloc(VALUE klass, void *data, RUBY_DATA_FUNC dmark, RUBY_DATA_FUNC dfree)

^

fast.c:1280:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum'

        case T_FIXNUM:  type = rb_cFixnum;      break;

                               ^

1 warning and 1 error generated.

make: *** [fast.o] Error 1



make failed, exit code 2



Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/oj-2.12.14 for inspection.

Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/oj-2.12.14/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fixnum is no longer a thing in ruby 2.4. Either downgrade your ruby or update oj to 2.16.1, which supports ruby 2.4.

Comment: I tried to upgrade oj to 2.16.1 and it worked. However, again when I tried to bundle install... it gave me the same error saying to make sure that `gem install oj -v '2.12.14'` succeeds before bundling. So, next idea was to downgrade Ruby as you suggested, but how do I do that just for this repository? I think the issue I am having is that I have setup ruby successfully, but I cloned a repository and perhaps it has code that is dependent upon either an older version of ruby or a different version of oj. I am assuming I should use RVM to somehow set the Ruby version for this repository?

Comment: @KramerKeller you need to update oj to the latest version in Gemfile.lock by running `bundle update oj` before running `bundle install`. that being said, it's always a good idea to manage your ruby installations using rvm or another manager. most managers figure out which version of ruby to use by looking for a _.ruby-version_ file in the directory. i wouldn't be surprised if the repository you cloned already had one.

Comment: I removed RVM completely. I also deleted my repository. I started a new file and cloned the repository and have rbenv working. I can see I am running 2.3.1 locally, but I am still getting the same error. It says "An error occurred while installing oj (2.12.14), and Bundler cannot continue." Bundle update oj gives the same error. Gem install seems to reference ruby 2.4... so how do I get gems for 2.3.1 to work with my cloned repo? I also checked my gem file and it says 'oj', '~> 2.12.14'  AND Gemfile.lock says oj (2.12.14). I am trying to learn ruby... but can't get it working on my machine.

Comment: I followed these instructions https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-rbenv-to-manage-rubies-and-gems AND for the first time I am at least getting a different error. I used Ruby 2.3.1. Now it is doing the same things as before though, but with the following error - An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.